# Why Firebase Database is not working in release app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a question about Firebase. When I compiled app in debug mode, everything works fine, but when I signed my app and trying to get data from Firebase database, the app stops. I'm added SHA-1 fingerprint to Firebase settings, generate new .json services file, uploaded it in to the app folder, but nothing changes. I'm getting error, when I'm trying to run my app in release mode ant get data. It was very strange, that all class names is changed into some dash and letters. Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: lt.ktu.treespectator, PID: 17622
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
    at lt.ktu.treespectator.TreesActivity$d.a(SourceFile:109)
    at b.a.b.i.m$a.a(SourceFile:179)
    at b.a.b.i.t.a0.a(SourceFile:75)
    at b.a.b.i.t.i0.d.a(SourceFile:63)
    at b.a.b.i.t.i0.g$a.run(SourceFile:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7520)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

And this is the piece of code where I'm trying to get data:

```
    private void initData() {
    final DatabaseReference ref;
    final String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserTrees");
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot data) {
            trees.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot ds : data.getChildren()) {
                **109 line:** if (ds.child("owner").getValue().toString().equals(android_id))
                {
                    String id = ds.child("id").getValue(String.class);
                    String age = ds.child("age").getValue(String.class);
                    String description = ds.child("description").getValue(String.class);
                    String diameter = ds.child("diameter").getValue(String.class);
                    String edited = ds.child("edited").getValue(String.class);
                    String height = ds.child("height").getValue(String.class);
                    String imageUrl = ds.child("imageUrl").getValue(String.class);
                    String kind = ds.child("kind").getValue(String.class);
                    String location = ds.child("location").getValue(String.class);
                    String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                    String owner = ds.child("owner").getValue(String.class);
                    String startDate = ds.child("startDate").getValue(String.class);
                    trees.add(new UserTree(id, name, age, height, diameter, kind, startDate, edited, description, owner, imageUrl, location));
                }
            }

            final TreeListAdapter userTrees= new TreeListAdapter(trees);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(userTrees);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getResources().getString(R.string.database_error) + " " + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Data in Firebase:
[Firebase data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRez0.png)

Comment: The query is just not returning the results you expect.  Your code should check if the snapshot contains the data you want.  Note that `getValue` can return null and you shouldn't call methods on its result until after you check that.

Comment: But why class names changes?

Comment: That's just the obfuscation applied to release builds.

Comment: But I have data in my database, so in my case it can't return null

Comment: We can't verify that because we can't see the data ourselves.  Please edit the question to show the data. A screenshot might help.

Comment: Screenshot was added. As I mentioned before, everything works fine in debug mode

Comment: Maybe I need to change something in proguard-rules.pro file?

Comment: There's no evidence that the problem you're seeing is due to obfuscation.  It seems to be the case that getValue() is just returning null due to lack of data.

Comment: But I'm getting all data in debug mode. :/

Comment: I have the same problem :(